# Can I use gitlab artifactory to upload some internal jars required to build maven java project

Tags: java, maven, jar, gitlab, artifact

I am working on running my project on gitlab cicd runners but one of my project is picking up jars from local. I have all the jars on our network artifactory hence cannot be given access to gitlab.

Temporarily I have added all the jars with my projects (I know its bad). Can I use gitlab artifactory to upload all the dependent jars and point maven to pick jars from there. I am not sure this is my first time working with runner. Is there any other better option to do this?